# Bootcamp still shows on startup even after I completely delete partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, startup

I use High Sierra and I had installed Windows on bootcamp partition.

I had a problem with Windows so so I decided to do a complete re-install.

So I deleted partition during the Windows installation process (by booting up using a Windows installation USB drive, and selected option to format and then delete Bootcamp partition) and I had also completely deleted the Bootcamp partition using Disk Utility whilst on the macOS.

However, when I press the alt key on boot, the Windows option still shows up on start up!

Obvious when I select it, it shows a blue screen saying Windows needs to be repaired, as the partition is deleted.

I completely formatted my Mac drive and re-installed macOS High Sierra but I still see the Windows option on startup. I just want to remove this now, I have tried everything.
Please see details of DiskUtil list below. Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!!

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
  #:            TYPE NAME          SIZE    IDENTIFIER
  0:   FDisk_partition_scheme            *2.0 TB   disk0
  1:        Windows_NTFS exFAT          2.0 TB   disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
  #:            TYPE NAME          SIZE    IDENTIFIER
  0:   GUID_partition_scheme            *1.0 TB   disk1
  1:            EFI EFI           209.7 MB  disk1s1
  2:         Apple_APFS Container disk2     1000.0 GB disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
  #:            TYPE NAME          SIZE    IDENTIFIER
  0:   APFS Container Scheme -           +1000.0 GB disk2
                 Physical Store disk1s2
  1:        APFS Volume macOS          11.8 GB  disk2s1
  2:        APFS Volume Preboot         28.6 MB  disk2s2
  3:        APFS Volume Recovery        516.2 MB  disk2s3
  4:        APFS Volume VM           2.1 GB   disk2s4
```

Comment: If Windows was installed to UEFI boot, then there could still exist Windows files the EFI partition (`disk1s1`).

Comment: Thanks, I run this command in the terminal to mount the EFI disk: sudo diskutil mount /dev/disk1s1
But there is nothing in the EFI folder apart from the Apple folder. There is no Boot or Microsoft folder whatsoever? Any idea? Thanks man

Comment: Is there a way I can completely erase everything? I just want to get rid of the Windows option at startup.
I don't mind starting from scratch, I have no data on my macOS or Bootcamp partition anyway.

Comment: Can anyone assist? I just want to remove the Windows option when I hold down the alt key to trigger the startup.
Is there a way I can erase everything? I don't have any data on the Bootcamp or mac partition.
Any advice?

Comment: What model/year Mac do you have?

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson I have a late 2012 Mac mini

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -f /dev/zero -u -y /dev/disk1`, then post the output from `sudo fdisk /dev/disk1`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, thanks for your help. The Apple disk switch to disk0 now after I run first aid. So obtained the details for Disk 0:

Comment: Fongs-Mac-mini:~ fongwong$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0

Disk: /dev/disk0 geometry: 121601/255/63 [1953525168 sectors]

Signature: 0xAA55


         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 - 1953525167] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused

Comment: I do not know what you mean by *"The Apple disk switch to disk0 now after I run first aid". Did this happen before or after entering the command `sudo fdisk -f /dev/zero -u -y /dev/disk1`? Or did you change the command to `sudo fdisk -f /dev/zero -u -y /dev/disk0`? System Integrity Protection (SIP) should have prevented the command `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`, so how were you able get output from this command?

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, I mean it happened before I ran: sudo fdisk -f /dev/zero -u -y /dev/disk1

Comment: #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1000.0 GB  disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:               Windows_NTFS exFAT                   2.0 TB     disk1s1

Comment: Yes, I changed the command to: sudo fdisk -f /dev/zero -u -y /dev/disk0

Comment: Run both `fdisk -f /dev/zero -u -y /dev/disk0` and `fdisk -f /dev/zero -u -y /dev/disk1` from macOS Recovery. Post the output from both `fdisk /dev/disk0` and `fdisk /dev/disk1`.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, these are the results below. Sorry I don't know how to transfer the text from terminal in macOS recovery, so I took a picture of the results and used google translate to obtain the text from the picture:

Comment: [ -bash - 3.2 # fdisk / dev / disk0 geometry : 121601/255/63 [ 1953525168 sectors ] Disk : / dev / disk0 Signature : 0xAA55 Starting Ending # : id cyl hd sec - cyl hd sec [ start - size ] 1 : EE 1023 254 63 - 1023 254 63 [ 1 1953525167 ] < Unknown ID > 2:00 0 0 0 0 0 0 [ 0 0 ] unused 3 : 00 0 0 0 0 0 0 [ 0 0 ] unused 4 : 00 0 0 0 0 0 0 [ 0 0 ] unused

Comment: -bash - 3.2 # fdisk / dev / disk1 Disk : / dev / disk1 geometry : 520/128/63 [ 4193992 sectors ] Signature : 0xAA55 Starting Ending # : id cyl hd sec - cyl hd sec [ start size ] 1 : EE 1023 254 63 1023 254 63 [ 1 4193991 ] < Unknown ID > 2:00 0 0 0 0 0 0 [ 0 0 ] unused 0 ] unused 3 : 00 0 0 0 0 0 0 [ 0 4 : 00 0 0 0 0 0 [ 0 0 ] unused -bash - 3.2 # 0

Comment: You can use Copy to transfer text from Terminal in macOS Recovery. You can use Paste to transfer text to Safari in macOS Recovery. The same in true in macOS. You should edit you question and post text there. Observe how nohillside did this.